# Pointcut to method implementation

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I created an Aspect with a pointcut to annotated method. What I get as `JoinPoint` is method declaration from Interface not method implementation. So when I want to get annotated method parameters I have to add annotation in interface not in implementation.

```
@AfterReturning(value = "@annotation(pl.styall.scylla.security.authorization.acl.AclSecure) && @annotation(aclSecure)", argNames = "jp,aclSecure,retVal", returning = "retVal")
public void addObjectAndEntry(JoinPoint jp, AclSecure aclSecure,
        Object retVal) {
    System.out.println(jp.toLongString());
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) jp.getSignature();
    Method method = signature.getMethod();
    Annotation[][] methodAnnotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
```

`methodAnnotations` has no annotations if they are add in method implementation. What would be the correct pointcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final String methodName = pjp.getSignature().getName();
final MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature)pjp.getSignature();
Method method = methodSignature.getMethod();
if (method.getDeclaringClass().isInterface()) {
    method = pjp.getTarget().getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, method.getParameterTypes());    
}
```

Source: [Spring AOP: how to get the annotations of the adviced method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559255/spring-aop-how-to-get-the-annotations-of-the-adviced-method)