# Jackson JSON, filtering properties by path

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I need to filter bean properties dynamiclly on serialization.

The `@JsonView` isn't an option for me.

Assume my Bean (as Json notation):

```
{
   id: '1',
   name: 'test',
   children: [
      { id: '1.1', childName: 'Name 1.1' },
      { id: '1.2', childName: 'Name 1.2' }
   ]
}
```

I want to write the JSON with the following properties:

```
// configure the ObjectMapper to only serialize this properties:
[ "name", "children.childName" ]
```

The expected JSON result is:

```
{
   name: 'test',
   children: [
      { childName: 'Name 1.1' },
      { childName: 'Name 1.2' }
   ]
}
```

Finally I will create an annotation (`@JsonFilterProperties`) to use with Spring in my RestControllers, something like this:

```
@JsonFilterProperties({"name", "children.childName"}) // display only this fields
@RequestMapping("/rest/entity")
@ResponseBody
public List<Entity> findAll() {
     return serviceEntity.findAll(); // this will return all fields populated!
}
```

Comment: Can't you use @JsonIgnore

Comment: No @SercanOzdemir, I can't because this must be configured by the caller and not statically. Each caller can configure different paths to serialize.

Comment: Allright then use [Mixin](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations)

Comment: Can you have a super class for your child objects that features only the properties you require?

Comment: No @Mena (take a look again at the end-of-question, I have improved details)

Answer (score 5):

Well, it's tricky but doable. You can do this using Jacksons `Filter` feature (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter) with some minor alterations. To start, we are going to use class name for filter id, this way you won't have to add `@JsonFIlter` to every entity you use:

```
public class CustomIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {

    @Override
    public Object findFilterId(AnnotatedClass ac) {
        return ac.getRawType();
    }
}
```

Next step, make that filter of super class will apply to all of its subclasses:

```
public class CustomFilterProvider extends SimpleFilterProvider {

    @Override
    public BeanPropertyFilter findFilter(Object filterId) {
        Class id = (Class) filterId;
        BeanPropertyFilter f = null;
        while (id != Object.class && f == null) {
            f = _filtersById.get(id.getName());
            id = id.getSuperclass();
        }
        // Part from superclass
        if (f == null) {
            f = _defaultFilter;
            if (f == null && _cfgFailOnUnknownId) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No filter configured with id '" + filterId + "' (type " + filterId.getClass().getName() + ")");
            }
        }
        return f;
    }
}
```

Custom version of `ObjectMapper` that utilizes our custom classes:

```
public class JsonObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    CustomFilterProvider filters;

    public JsonObjectMapper() {
        filters = new CustomFilterProvider();
        filters.setFailOnUnknownId(false);
        this.setFilters(this.filters);
        this.setAnnotationIntrospector(new CustomIntrospector());
    }

    /* You can change methods below as you see fit. */

    public JsonObjectMapper addFilterAllExceptFilter(Class clazz, String... property) {
        filters.addFilter(clazz.getName(), SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(property));
        return this;
    }

    public JsonObjectMapper addSerializeAllExceptFilter(Class clazz, String... property) {
        filters.addFilter(clazz.getName(), SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(property));
        return this;
    }        

}
```

Now take a look at `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, you will see that it uses one instane of `ObjectMapper` internaly, ergo you cannot use it if you want  different configurations simultaneously (for different requests). You need request scoped `ObjectMapper` and appropriate message converter that uses it:

```
public abstract class DynamicMappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {

    // Spring will override this method with one that provides request scoped bean
    @Override
    public abstract ObjectMapper getObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void setObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        // We dont need that anymore
    }

    /* Additionally, you need to override all methods that use objectMapper  attribute and change them to use getObjectMapper() method instead */

}
```

Add some bean definitions:

```
<bean id="jsonObjectMapper" class="your.package.name.JsonObjectMapper" scope="request">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="your.package.name.DynamicMappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            <lookup-method name="getObjectMapper" bean="jsonObjectMapper"/>              
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>       
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

And the last part is to implement something that will detect your annotation and perform actual configuration. For that you can create an `@Aspect`. Something like:

```
@Aspect
public class JsonResponseConfigurationAspect {

@Autowired
private JsonObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Around("@annotation(jsonFilterProperties)")
public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    /* Here you will have to determine return type and annotation value from jointPoint object. */
    /* See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559255/spring-aop-how-to-get-the-annotations-of-the-adviced-method for more info */
    /* If you want to use things like 'children.childName' you will have to  use reflection to determine 'children' type, and so on. */    
}
```

}

Personally, I use this in a different way. I dont use annotations and just do configuration manually:

```
@Autowired
private JsonObjectMapper objectMapper;

@RequestMapping("/rest/entity")
@ResponseBody
public List<Entity> findAll() {
    objectMapper.addFilterAllExceptFilter(Entity.class, "name", "children"); 
    objectMapper.addFilterAllExceptFilter(EntityChildren.class, "childName"); 
    return serviceEntity.findAll();
}
```

P.S. This approach has one major flaw: you cannot add two different filters for one class.

Comment: Is there any working github link for the code above?

Comment: Im afraid no, unless someone else put it there.

Answer (score 1):

There's Jackson plugin called [squiggly](https://github.com/bohnman/squiggly) for doing exactly this.

```java
String filter = "name,children[childName]";
ObjectMapper mapper = Squiggly.init(this.objectMapper, filter);
mapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), myBean);
```

You could integrate it into a `MessageConverter` or similar, driven by annotations, as you see fit.

---

If you have a fixed number of possible options, then there is a static solution too: [`@JsonView`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonView.html)

```java
public interface NameAndChildName {}
```

```java
@JsonView(NameAndChildName.class)
@ResponseBody
public List<Entity> findAll() {
     return serviceEntity.findAll();
}
```

```java
public class Entity {
    public String id;

    @JsonView(NameAndChildName.class)
    public String name;

    @JsonView({NameAndChildName.class, SomeOtherView.class})
    public List<Child> children;
}
```

```
public class Child {
    @JsonView(SomeOtherView.class)
    public String id;

    @JsonView(NameAndChildName.class)
    public String childName;
}
```

Comment: Squiggly is a great find, but is not currently maintained.