# How to read path variables or URL parameters in Custom deserializer Spring Boot

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

I've written a custom deserializer for an entity in Spring Boot application. Now I need to access URL parameters and path variables in my custom deserializer for some data manipulation. Please tell me how can i do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For path variables deserialization you don't need to involve jackson but you have to "tune" Spring MVC itself by means of defining your own [org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#core-convert-Converter-API)

For example:

```
@Component
public class StringToLocalDateTimeConverter
  implements Converter<String, LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convert(String source) {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(
          source, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
    }
}

@GetMapping("/findbydate/{date}")
public GenericEntity findByDate(@PathVariable("date") LocalDateTime date) {
    return ...;
}
```

[Here is an article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder) about it.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`

See [spring-mvc-custom-data-binder](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder#1-custom-argument-resolver), [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46213051/5172925)

#### 2. `HandlerInterceptor`

See [Interception](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor)