# Filter object elements with Jayway Jsonpath

Tags: java, json, serialization, jsonpath, jayway

I have a list of (somehow "well-behaved") jsonpaths and I have to return an object which contains only the elements described in the list. For example, given the list `["$.a.a2", $.c]` and the object

```
{
    "a": {"a1": 1, "a2": 2},
    "b": foo,
    "c": []
}
```

the desired result is

```
{
    "a": {"a2": 2},
    "c": []
}
```

I'm using [Jayway Jsonpath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath), but I'm open to use other libraries. My current solution is the following:

- find the minimal jsonpath list that describe the same set of elements (i.e. remove `"$.a.a2"` if `"$.a"` is present);
- determine the leaf objects (in the first example `a2` and `c`) and build a map that is capable to contain them, as creation of deep nodes is still [not supported](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/83): in the first example, after this step I'm creating a map `{"a": {}}`;
- read the values from the initial object and copy them in the map with the provided methods `read`/`set`.

I'm quite surprised that such feature is not present. Is there a better way to filter properties in an object? [Squiggly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64577801/11478354) might be a suitable solution, but is not maintained.

Answer (score 1):

You may try another JSON library *Josson* using query expression with function `map()`.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"a\": {\"a1\": 1, \"a2\": 2}," +
    "    \"b\": \"foo\"," +
    "    \"c\": []" +
    "}");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("map(a.map(a2), c)");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "a" : {
    "a2" : 2
  },
  "c" : [ ]
}
```

You can compare the structure of the JSON output with this re-formatted query expression:

```
map(
  a.map(
    a2
  ),
  c
)
```

Comment: Josson looks exactly what I need. The issue now is to convert jsonpath to josson notation. I will play around a bit, thank you.